# Which floating point operations generate quiet/signalling NaN?

Tags: floating-point, nan, ieee-754

I'm designing an FPU in a logic simulator and I need to know which operations generate the two kinds of NaNs (quiet: qNaN and signalling: sNaN)

edit: I've found out that arithmetic operations like 0*infinity always generate qNaNs (source: http://www.savrola.com/resources/NaN.html). What I still don't know however is if there are any other ways to get sNaNs beside setting a variable to sNaN's bit pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have some sort of textbook or spec on whatever floating point spec you intend to simulate. Look in there for definitions.

For something more general, you can read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN

Here is what wikipedia says on sNaNs:

> **Signaling NaN**
> Signaling NaNs, or sNaNs, are special forms of a
> NaN that when consumed by most operations should raise an invalid
> exception and then, if appropriate, be "quieted" into a qNaN that may
> then propagate. They were introduced in IEEE 754. There have been
> several ideas for how these might be used
>
> - Filling uninitialized memory with signaling NaNs would produce an invalid exception if the data is used before it is initialized
> - Using an sNaN as a placeholder for a more complicated object, such as:
>
>   - A representation of a number that has underflowed
>   - A representation of a number that has overflowed
>   - Number in a higher precision format
>   - A complex number

Comment: The wiki article is just for general reference. The real meat is the first part of my answer. If you have no reference for floating point numbers and operations, how exactly do you plan on creating an FPU in the simulator?

Comment: So, it appears you actual question is are there valid FP operations which in the process of generating an output, would generate sNaNs the way qNaNs are generated.

Answer is no. That's based on a simple reading of sNaNs in the wikipedia article. I suggest you read that section again.

Comment: Ah thanks. I thought the wiki was incomplete because it said "should raise an exception" and I immediatly associated that with arithmetic operations like division by zero.

Comment: Yes, the language used for qNaNs and sNaNs is slightly confusing since they use the same terms to have slightly different meaning. But yes, the sNaNs would need to have a specific bit pattern set.